# Unicode characters in Hive

Tags: unicode, hadoop, hive

I tried to group by unicode text with unicode characters in hive and the reducer failed miserably. Hive faces a run time exception. Does hive support unicode characters at all?

Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{"reducesinkkey0":"h�ngekommode ","reducesinkkey1":"1 "},"value":{"_col0":"h�ngekommode ","_col1":"1 "},"alias":0}

Comment: Is there any way to post the characters that you were originally using?  At the moment, it looks like a question mark in my browser...

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop and Hive support UTF8 encoding. This is an implicit assumption in many places in the Hadoop and Hive codebases. You will need to convert your data to UTF8.

What was the actual exception you got? You can find it in the job logs.